# How can I use java recursion with this relation

Tags: java, recursion

I need to use java recursion using this relation.

Xn = 1.5 * X(n-1)(1-X(n-1))

I am completely lost. Please help

```
public static int factorial(int N) { 
        if (N == 1) return 1; 
        return N * factorial(N-1); 
    }
```

This is the code that I have for basic recursion without the relation.

X1 should return 0.375
X10 should return 0.33339

Comment: What is the starting condition, i.e. the value for `X0` or some `X`?

Comment: if you have this recursive call as relation what stops you from returning `return 1.5 * factorial(n-1) * (1-factorial(n-1))`?

Comment: because when I enter X1 for the value N. It just returns 1 but it should returh 0.375

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write it out:

Xn = 1.5 * X(n-1)(1-X(n-1))

so:

```
public static final int X(int n){
  return 1.5 * (X(n-1)*(1-X(n-1)));
}
```

of course, you need to know when to stop, so it will be:

```
public static final double X(int n){
  if(n==1)
     return 0.375;
  return 1.5 * (X(n-1)*(1-X(n-1)));
}
```